# Is there a way to draw multiple circles with Turtle based on user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, geometry, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I want to create something that looks like this: [many circles of the same size next to each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUeNc.png)

However, I want the number of circles to be determined by user input. I can't seem to find any information on how I might go about this.

Here's what i have so far but it does not accomplish my goals.

```py
import turtle
 
print("How many circles?")
circnum = input()

#Summoning the turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()

#circling the circle
for i in circnum:
  r = 25
  t.circle(r)
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `circnum` a number so that you can make a `range` to iterate over, and you need to move the turtle in between circles so you aren't just drawing the same circle on top of itself over and over.

```
import turtle
 
print("How many circles?")
circnum = int(input())

#Summoning the turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()

#circling the circle
for _ in range(circnum):
  t.circle(25)
  t.forward(5)
```

Comment: This works exactly like i imagined, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Samwise's suggestions (+1) but if you're using standard Python 3 turtle, and not some older version or subset, I say get rid of `input()` and go full turtle on it:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

RADIUS = 25
DISTANCE = 10

screen = Screen()

number_circles = screen.numinput("A Circle in a Spiral", "How many circles?", default=10, minval=1, maxval=30)

if number_circles:
    # Summoning the turtle
    turtle = Turtle()
    turtle.speed('fast')  # because I have little patience

    # Circling the circle
    for _ in range(int(number_circles)):  # numinput() returns a float
        turtle.circle(RADIUS)
        turtle.forward(DISTANCE)

    screen.exitonclick()
else:
    # user hit 'Cancel' in the number input dialog
    screen.bye()
```

Comment: When i try to run this (I'm using Replit, don't know if that matters) I get an error on line 8: AttributeError: 'Screen' object has no attribute 'numinput' on line 8

Comment: @ManganeseHeptoxide, yes, Repl.it is an example of what I referred to as a turtle 'subset' in my preamble.  They don't use the turtle.py that comes with Python but rather their own implementation to make it work in the web browser.